# Push/Present Modal View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, controller

I have a table in my view controller (let's call it TVC1). I have rows in TVC1 that are used so the user can input some more data in addition to the data on TVC1. So, when someone taps a specific row in TVC1, it will show another view controller (let's call it TVC2). However, when TVC2 is shown, all of the data in TVC1 is cleared. How can I save the data in TVC1? Should I do it through the app delegate?

```
        DescriptionInputViewController *descriptionController = [[DescriptionInputViewController alloc] 
                                                             initWithNibName:@"DescriptionInputView" 
                                                             bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:descriptionController animated:YES];
    [descriptionController release];
```

Comment: Can you post more information, please? How do you call TVC2? If you simply pop it onto the view controller stack, how and where do you do so?

Comment: I push it, I posted the code there. I tried pushViewController:animated: and displayModalViewController:animated: both clear the data. (descriptionViewController would be TVC2)

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you should be calling:

```
[self presentModalViewController:descriptionController animated:YES]
```

descriptionController is the view controller you are displaying.