# Open "Modal" Widow and close in TabGroup Based Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modal-dialog, titanium-mobile

Should Also have specified, I am developing this using Titanium Mobile.

I have a tabbed application. I have the need to open a  "modal" like window for the purpose of allowing the user to enter some settings.

For example, you click the 3rd tab in the tabGroup. Some logic runs to see if a setting is set before continuing to create the view. The setting is not in place, so a new window animates in asking you to create this setting. After you create the setting, it closes and the view continues to render, or refreshes.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I have created the window, animated it into the current tab, and I have even successfully closed it. Getting the view to refresh or re-load is what is difficult. Also, the navigation bar offers the user the ability to navigate back to the window to change the setting, which I also do not want.

Any way to accomplish this?
I have the same need for logging the user into the application.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244197/push-present-modal-view-controller

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I am developing using Titanium Mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

windowbject.open({modal:true});

This will only works in iOS.

And you want to refresh view which is behind this modal window then you have to add "focus" eventlistener to the window and write code in it.This code will execute when ever window got focus.
So when you close "modal" view then window behind it will get focus.

I hope this will help you.